# Use new column created from CASE

Tags: sql, concatenation, case

This is a section of SQL I have:

```
  select 
  ,V_QUOTE_CASE_OPP_FROM2020.SR_NUM
  ,V_SF_OPPORTUNITY_ITEMS.PROD_FAMILY
  ,case 
                     when PROD_FAMILY like '%Tax%' then 'Tax'
                     when PROD_FAMILY like '%Practice Manager%' then 'Practice Manager'
                     when PROD_FAMILY like '%Compliance%' then 'Compliance'
                     else PROD_FAMILY end as PRODUCT_FAMILY
  ,CONCAT(V_QUOTE_CASE_OPP_FROM2020.SR_NUM, PRODUCT_FAMILY) as 'RN_PRODFAM'

  FROM [COMMOPSDB].[dbo].[V_QUOTE_CASE_OPP_FROM2020]

  LEFT JOIN [COMMOPSDB].[dbo].[V_SF_OPPORTUNITY_ITEMS]
```

(this is an abridged version).

The problem I have is that the CONCAT isn't working - it says "Invalid column name 'Product Family'" when I run it.

I have tried replacing PRODUCT_FAMILY with V_SF_OPPORTUNITY_ITEMS.PRODUCT_FAMILY, with the same result.

What am I doing wrong please?

Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as functionality and syntax varies between them. It avoids wasting both your time and the time of users who try to answer your question only to be told it doesn't work in the DBMS you're using.

Comment: Fair call - sorry!

Comment: But you didn't [edit] your post to add that tag yet. Please do so now.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t refer to a new column only created in the select statement in that same statement. Easiest solution is to use a CTE ie.

```sql
with temp as (  select 
  ,V_QUOTE_CASE_OPP_FROM2020.SR_NUM
  ,V_SF_OPPORTUNITY_ITEMS.PROD_FAMILY
  ,case 
     when PROD_FAMILY like '%Tax%' then 'Tax'
     when PROD_FAMILY like '%Practice Manager%' then 'Practice Manager'
     when PROD_FAMILY like '%Compliance%' then 'Compliance'
     else PROD_FAMILY end as PRODUCT_FAMILY
    )
Select [can now reference temp.PROD_FAMILY]
```